# Find the slope of the secant line with two points

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to figure out this problem.

> The point P(1,0) lies on the curve $y=\sin(10\pi/x)$. 
>   If Q is the point $(x,\sin(\frac{10\pi}{x}))$, find the slope of the secant line PQ (correct to four decimal places) for x = 2.

I have tried doing the slope formula $\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$.

since $\sin(\frac{10\pi}{2}) = 0.2707$ I think that, when $x = 2$, $Q = (2,0.2707)$.

since $P = (1, 0)$, the slope formula becomes, $\frac{.2707 - 0}{2 - 1} = 0.2707$

But this answer is wrong. How can I get the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin\frac{10\pi}2=\sin5\pi=\sin\pi=0$$
I assume that you used degrees instead of radians to calculate the sine.

Comment: That's what my problem was! Thanks!